# Update Manager Refuses to Update

Tags: update-manager, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

It seems I've run into a small issue after installing Ubuntu 11.10.
After the installation of the upgrade, everything worked fine for a while. One day I went into "UPDATE MANAGER" and checked for updates (This is due to all the recent downloads I made, so I was curious to know if they had to be updated for better use.), but after it read all the updates a error message appeared...

Failed to download repository information

Check your Internet connection.

I then clicked Details to view the problem... (This is what appeared under 'Details')

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bisigi/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

(Please excuse me for this, and I do apologize. I'm very new at Ubuntu and I'd appreciate some assistance with this. Thanks.)

Edit:

Further information:

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/786323/

`sudo apt-get update`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/786326/

`sudo apt-get upgrade`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/786329/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bisigi does not have a PPA repo for Oneiric - my suggestion is to untick this PPA in your *software sources* and then rerun *Update  Manager* or for a terminal.

Find both by searching from the Dash.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

your sources.list look OK

however the `sudo apt-get update` list looks like you have several "karmic" PPAs - please look through your "software software" list in software sources and untick all of these PPAs.

Your `sudo apt-get upgrade` is probably the most worry and will explain why you haven't seen any updates for a while.

There is a useful [sticky-thread on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=723361) describing just this issue and its resolution.

If you change the hostname in `/etc/hostname`, you must also fix up `/etc/hosts` so the new name resolves to 127.0.1.1. The safest way is to edit hosts and add the new name, then edit hostname, then o back to hosts to remove the old hostname.

[image]

My `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` file is shown - you will need to use your hostname

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package files.[13] aptitude has a smarter dist-upgrade feature called full-upgrade.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade