# Update Manager cannot find repos when upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, server, upgrade

I cannot seem to upgrade from 11.04 to Oneiric because:

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multivers/binary-amd64/Packages
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80], W:Failed to fetch
gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_main_binary-i386_Packages
Hash Sum mismatch, W:Failed to fetch
gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-security_universe_binary-i386_Packages
Hash Sum mismatch, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or
```

old ones used instead.

Now I thought I would check my network connection despite the fact that it could find every other package and it ofc returned that my network was fine. So I decided to ping the IP of this package location myself (91.189.92.167) and got:

```
PING 91.189.92.167 (91.189.92.167) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=40.5 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=2 ttl=128 time=39.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=3 ttl=128 time=41.0 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=4 ttl=128 time=38.7 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=5 ttl=128 time=41.1 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.167: icmp_req=6 ttl=128 time=38.6 ms

--- 91.189.92.167 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.658/39.967/41.195/1.038 ms
```

Which meant everything was dandy on that side. So I thought maybe the host cannot be resolved so I did host -v:

```
sam@ubuntu:~$ host -v security.ubuntu.com
Trying "security.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30243
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;security.ubuntu.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
security.ubuntu.com.    5       IN      A       91.189.92.167
security.ubuntu.com.    5       IN      A       91.189.92.166

Received 69 bytes from 192.168.153.2#53 in 37 ms
Trying "security.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42468
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;security.ubuntu.com.           IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             5       IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com.hostmaster.ca     nonical.com. 2012011402 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 98 bytes from 192.168.153.2#53 in 39 ms
Trying "security.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23755
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;security.ubuntu.com.           IN      MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             5       IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com.hostmaster.ca    nonical.com. 2012011402 10800 3600 604800 3600
Received 98 bytes from 192.168.153.2#53 in 40 ms
```

Which again looks just dandy so I am stuck with thinking that for some reason it has to be something with:

```
Hash Sum mismatch, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or
old ones used instead.
```

So I did a little searching and found a problem with ppa repos: [Update Manager Refuses to Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91119/update-manager-refuses-to-update)

But the thing is I am not using ppa so that cant be my problem.

Does anyone know what else could be stopping me from upgrading my Ubuntu?

Maybe I am overlooking something that is right in front my eyes and its just past my bed time, either way I am totally stumped.

Thanks,

EDIT: Also when I try and do a sudo apt-get update now I get:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used     instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your sources.list (`multivers` instead of `multiverse` for oneiric-security repository) which causes the *404 Not Found* error

For those two *Hash Sum mismatch* errors: Remove the files in */var/lib/apt/lists/partial/* and try to update again.

If you still get this error download `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz`, calculate the MD5 checksum and compare it with the one in http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release

Do they match?

Comment: Thanks, removing the partials worked, got another problem now though, would you know what: 
E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2) basically is?

Comment: Oh I actually solved this with some very sneaky google keywords! Thanks for the help :)