# Ubuntu server upgrade 11.04 to 11.10 fails

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, upgrade

I'm actually trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 11.04 server to 12.04, but I have to go through 11.10 first, right? Well, `do-release-upgrade` is failing miserably. Here is the output, with duplicate lines and such removed (still > 1500 lines): http://paste.ubuntu.com/1018546/

Yeah. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96022/update-manager-cannot-find-repos-when-upgrading-to-11-10), which seems to mention similar errors, but I've tried all of the suggestions given there and nothing has changed.

I tried running `apt-get dist-upgrade`; it churned for a while and eventually came back with "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"  Ran `apt-get update` and got much the same kinds of error messages I got from `do-release-upgrade`.

The following are samples of the outputs that raise my eyebrow (line numbers reference the pastebin code):

- `Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease` (e.g. line 43)--don't know if this is a problem or not, but it shows up frequently
- `Err http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages` (e.g. line 101)
- `bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.` (e.g. line 117)
- `404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]` (e.g. line 199)--when this occurs, it always occurs after one of the `Err` lines
- `Updating repository information
  WARNING: Failed to read mirror file` (e.g. lines 580-81)
- E.g. lines 1045-52:

  ```
  bzip2: Data integrity error when decompressing.
  Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

  It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
  You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

  You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
  data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.
  ```

And the summary of the whole train wreck can be found in lines 1520-65.

Any ideas/suggestions/solutions? (The `bzip2` errors particularly confuse me. It looks like it's trying to decompress from stdin? Is it supposed to do that?) Should I try downloading & upgrading from the ISO instead? *(Edit: ISO upgrade failed too.)* I'm glad to provide any further information I've forgotten.  TIA!

Comment: To provide text in your question (or for very long text, at http://paste.ubuntu.com) that would make it easier for people to help you, you might consider attempting the upgrade again, using [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/script.1.html) to record everything on the command-line, perhaps in conjunction with [`pastebinit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/pastebinit.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip--running it again with `script` right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My upgrade  to 11.10 finally worked! Here's the post-mortem:

Over the weekend, I did some more searching for similar problems--specifically 404 errors while upgrading. [This page](http://h3x.no/2010/11/08/ubuntu-apt-get-update-gives-404-not-found-error) among others suggested that it might just be a temporary problem with the mirror site. Okay, I thought, I'll try changing mirrors when I get in on Monday.

The first thing I tried to do Monday was install a software package. It failed, of course--this problem affects `apt-get` just as much as `do-release-upgrade`. Just for kicks, I ran `apt-get update` again, just to watch it fail--but this time it succeeded. I was able to install my package. Next I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`; it still had some errors, but fewer than before. So today, I tried the `do-release-upgrade`--and it worked. Hooray!

**FINAL DIAGNOSIS:** Temporary problems with the mirror site(s)--either us.archive.ubuntu.com, or security.ubuntu.com, or both. It's also possible I had transient network issues, although I think that's less likely.

**RECOMMENDED SOLUTION:** Wait a couple weeks and try again. If that doesn't work, switch mirrors. (See the [list of archive mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). I'm sure there are good online tutorials for how to switch, though I'm too lazy to look them up right now).

Hope this helps somebody. Now I'm off to see if I can get the upgrade to 12.04 to work! =^P